# DataBricks: Any way to reset the Generated IDENTITY column?

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, delta-lake

Delta tables have the capability to generate an identity column, like so:

```
CREATE TABLE TestMe (
  pKey bigint GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1),
  id bigint,
  commentary string
  )
 USING DELTA
 OPTIONS (PATH "/mnt/Delta/Testing/TestMe")
```

However, there seems to be no way to reset the counter without manually editing the changelog files which seems risky.

If I want to truncate the table and place a new set of data in there, how can I do that without slowly accumulating an identity column in the hundreds of millions / billions (every data insert the counter just goes up and never resets)?

Comment: Sorry, I'm understanding your actual requirement. Why do you want reset the identify value?

Comment: Lets say I truncate the table or vacuum it to remove all the data. When I add fresh data to it, why would I want the identity column to start at 1 billion (or whatever it was last at)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try this way

```
CREATE TABLE TestMe (
  pKey bigint GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1),
  id bigint,
  commentary string
);
  
insert into TestMe (id,commentary) values (1,'a'),(2,'b'),(3,'c');
  
select * from TestMe;
  
truncate table TestMe;

describe history TestMe;
  
Restore Table TestMe to version as of 0;

insert into TestMe (id,commentary) values (1,'a'),(2,'b'),(3,'c');
```

---

Alternative Answer works better

```
CREATE or REPLACE TABLE TestMe (
  pKey bigint GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1),
  id bigint,
  commentary string
);
  
insert into TestMe (id,commentary) values (1,'a'),(2,'b'),(3,'c');

select * from TestMe;

-- Rerun Create or Replace resets the identity

CREATE or REPLACE TABLE TestMe (
  pKey bigint GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1),
  id bigint,
  commentary string
);
```

Comment: Brilliant! I did not try to restore and start over!

Answer (score 1):

Found another way to solve

```
CREATE or REPLACE TABLE TestMe (
  pKey bigint GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1),
  id bigint,
  commentary string
);
  
insert into TestMe (id,commentary) values (1,'a'),(2,'b'),(3,'c');

select * from TestMe;

-- Rerun Create or Replace resets the identity

CREATE or REPLACE TABLE TestMe (
  pKey bigint GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1),
  id bigint,
  commentary string
);
```

Comment: it's better to add this to your accepted answer - just edit it & add as an alternative

Comment: This is probably the better long run solution. I am running into issues now with the first answer where version0 no longer exists in my table history, likely due to vacuum defaults?